# changing the colors on a contour plot and position of the labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

Above is an image of the contour plot. I am having difficulties with seeing the yellow color, so I was trying to change the colors. I am not sure how to change the colors. In addition, I was wondering how to change the position of the labels on the lines. Below is the code I used to create the graph. The code will extract values from a txt file that is in the following format

```
  1.0;3.0;0.11793
  1.0;23.0;0.1441
  1.0;43.0;0.14525
  1.0;63.0;0.14554
  1.0;83.0;0.14541
  1.0;103.0;0.14533
  1.0;123.0;0.14533
```

There is a lot more data than this in the text file it extract from, but this just show an example whats in the txt file.

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from random import randint

  #----- EXTRACTS AND PROCESS DATA FROM .TXT FILE ------------------

  data_file = open('UC4results.txt','r') #opens file
  lines = data_file.readlines() #reads file
  data_file.close()
  r_list = [] #creates list
  h_list = []
  keff_list = []
  for i in range(len(lines)):
      lines[i] = lines[i].strip('\n')
      line_list = lines[i].split(';')
      r_list.append(float(line_list[0])) #grabs values in the first column 
      h_list.append(float(line_list[1])) #grabs values in the second column
      keff_list.append(float(line_list[2])) #grabs values in the third column

  R,H = np.meshgrid(np.unique(r_list),np.unique(h_list))

  R = 2*np.array(R)

  h_diam =[]
  for i in range(len(R)):
      placeholder = []
      for diam in range(len(R[0])):
          placeholder.append(H[i][diam]/(R[i][diam]))
      h_diam.append(placeholder)

  keff_array = []
  keff_storage = []
  count = 0
  for i in range(len(keff_list)):
      keff_storage.append(keff_list[i])
      count += 1
      if count % len(np.unique(r_list)) == 0:    # adds the list after its the appropriate length, and starts a new one
          keff_array.append(keff_storage)
          keff_storage = []

  plt.figure(figsize=(20,20), dpi=400)
  contour_graph = plt.contour(R,H,keff_array,[0.800,0.900,1.000,1.100,1.200]) #plots contour plot 

  plt.xlabel('Diameter (cm)', size = 30)
  plt.ylabel('Height (cm)', size = 30)
  plt.clabel(contour_graph, fontsize=20)
  plt.xticks(size = 30)
  plt.yticks(size = 30)
  plt.xlim(0,60)
  plt.ylim(0,60)
  plt.grid()
```

Comment: Are you sure this example is correct? I'm not able to run it, as there seems to be something wrong with the way you're building `keff_array`. Anyhow, having a look at the [docs for the `plt.contour()` function](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html), there seems to be a `colors` argument you can use. Try something like `plt.contour(R,H,keff_array,[0.800,0.900,1.000,1.100,1.200], colors=[color_1, color_2, color_3, ...])`, in which `color_i` can be `'red'`, `'blue'`, and so on.

Comment: yes I believe the code is correct. I just did what you said and it works correctly.